# DAO Class in java taking too much time to fetch Data

Tags: java

I have the following Data in my DAO class

```
public List<Environment> fetchMiddlewareVersions() throws SQLException{
      System.out.println("reached version");
      Environment environment;
      List<Environment> environments=new ArrayList<Environment>();
 try{
         connection=DBConnectionUtil.getConnection();
         statement=connection.createStatement();
         statement.setFetchSize(100);
         preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("select * from     middleware_version_details order by application,environment");
         resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                environment = new Environment();
                environment.setAppName(resultSet.getString("APPLICATION"));
                environment.setHostName(resultSet.getString("HOSTNAME"));
                environment.setSoftwareComponent(resultSet.getString("SOFTWARE_COMPONENT"));
                environment.setVersion(resultSet.getString("VERSION"));
                environment.setInstallPath(resultSet.getString("INSTALL_PATH"));
                environment.setRemarks(resultSet.getString("REMARKS"));
                environment.setEnvironmental(resultSet.getString("ENVIRONMENT"));
                environments.add(environment);  

            }
    }
```

By the time I get the entire data into JSP page, it has consumed 20-30 seconds already. How do I Increase speed of the Fetch. I tried DynaCache and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you do some profiling to find out where the bunch of that 20-30 seconds is spent? If it's spent at the database, then there is either too much data or most likely with the query. If the db returns quick enough, then we can look at the java piece. Typically, from the moment you click something on your JSP till you see data, there is more than one place where it could take time. Narrow it down and you might find the root cause for the slowness.

Comment: I guess you didn't paste whole method, since it does not return anything. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else, the code you provided  shouldn't cause such problems, even if the table is not indexed, has 100 columns etc.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wish to let you know where you might start debugging this. 1st - if you enter the query as-is into a SQL client - how long does it take? 2nd - use the column names in the query instead of asterisk ("*") - that goes with the next item 3rd - how many columns are there in the table? if there's a great many columns in the table that may also slow down the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So barring any sort of connectivity issues, it almost always comes down to the number of records you're fetching. If you're fetching A TON of records, the method will not return until it has gone through each item and created an array object.

I would try adding a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clause to your SQL Statement to only retrieve records, say, 25 at a time. `setFetchSize( int )` does not affect the number of overall records, only the number of records the underlying transport will fetch at a time from your sever. (also, move your SQL query into a static final variable:

```
 private static final String SQL_FETCH_MIDDLEWARE_VERSION = 
      "SELECT * FROM middleware_version_details order by application, environment " +
      "LIMIT = ? OFFSET = ?";
```

then set the limit and the offset in your prepared statement like so:

```
 preparedStatement.setInt( 1, <RECORD COUNT> );
 preparedStatement.setInt( 2, <RECORD START> );
```

Third, do you have an index on `application` and `environment`? If you do not and you will be constantly ordering, filtering and joining on those columns, you should add an index.

Fourth, and it's a minor point but one that I adhere to, is that doing `resultSet.getString( "<COLUMN NAME>" )` will cause another call to go look up the column index. It's not usually a huge deal, but if you're trying to be as performant as possible, you should use the numeric index. You can do this by creating private static variables holding the index:

```
 private static int INDEX_ENVIRONMENT = 6;
```

or you can use a counter  and just insure that the columns are in the correct order, something like this:

```
while(resultSet.next())
{
     int iC = 0;

     environment = new Environment();
     environment.setAppName(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setHostName(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setSoftwareComponent(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setVersion(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setInstallPath(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setRemarks(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environment.setEnvironmental(resultSet.getString( iC++ ));
     environments.add(environment);  
 }
```

Just insure that you're setting the variables in the correct order and it will be slightly more performant. I like this counter approach as well because it allows me to easily adapt to changing schemas.